# Flutter Cloud Firestore errors after Flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

With Flutter v1.9.1+hotfix.2 I get the below errors when attempting to build Android for release. Release build runs fine on device. iOS release build is fine.
Flutter Doctor output and packages also listed below.

I have tried multiple suggested solutions such as making sure migrated to androidX. Setting Android minSdkVersion to 23 and multiple other with no success.

> /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:100:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       return getFirestore(arguments).collectionGroup(path);
>                                     ^                                        symbol:   method collectionGroup(String)
>   location: class FirebaseFirestore
>   /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:128:
>   warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
>       Map documentData = (Map) document.get("data");
>                                                                            ^   required: Map
>   found:    Object
>   /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:135:
>   warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
>             Map current = (Map) documentData.get(fieldNameParts[0]);
>                                                                                 ^   required: Map
>   found:    Object
>   /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:137:
>   warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
>               current = (Map) current.get(fieldNameParts[i]);
>                                                          ^                   required: Map
>   found:    Object
>   /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:187:
>   warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
>         Map metadata = new HashMap();
>                                        ^                                     required: Map
>   found:    HashMap
>   /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:230:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           query = query.whereArrayContains(fieldName, value);
>                        ^                                                     symbol:   method whereArrayContains(String,Object)
>   location: variable query of type Query
>   /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:466:
>   warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
>                   Map metadata = new HashMap();
>                                                  ^                           required: Map
>   found:    HashMap
>   /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:808:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               builder.setCacheSizeBytes(((Integer) arguments.get("cacheSizeBytes")).longValue());
>                      ^                                                       symbol:   method setCacheSizeBytes(long)
>   location: variable builder of type Builder
>   /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:889:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           return FieldValue.arrayUnion(toArray(readValue(buffer)));
>                            ^                                                 symbol:   method arrayUnion(Object[])
>   location: class FieldValue
>   /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:891:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           return FieldValue.arrayRemove(toArray(readValue(buffer)));
>                            ^                                                 symbol:   method arrayRemove(Object[])
>   location: class FieldValue
>   /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:898:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           return FieldValue.increment(integerIncrementValue.intValue());
>                            ^                                                 symbol:   method increment(int)
>   location: class FieldValue
>   /Users/chris/Development/Packages/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.9+4/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java:901:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           return FieldValue.increment(doubleIncrementValue.doubleValue());
>                            ^                                                 symbol:   method increment(double)
>   location: class FieldValue

Flutter doctor output:

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [✓]
>   Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95,
>   locale en-ZA) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
>   (Android SDK version 29.0.2) [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
>   (Xcode 10.3) [✓] Android Studio (version 3.5) [✓] VS Code (version
>   1.38.1) [✓] Connected device (2 available)
>   • No issues found!

Packages:

> version: 1.0.1+21
>
> environment:   sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"
>
> dependencies:   flutter:
>       sdk: flutter
>
> intl: ^0.15.8   image: ^2.1.4   rxdart: ^0.22.0   provider: ^2.0.1
>   file_picker: ^1.3.7   fluttertoast: ^3.1.0   url_launcher: ^5.0.3
>   image_picker: ^0.6.0+10   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2   bottom_navy_bar:
>   ^5.1.0   firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+7   geoflutterfire: ^2.0.3+5
>   in_app_purchase: 0.2.0+4   firebase_storage: ^3.0.2
>   sliding_up_panel: ^0.3.4   cloud_firestore: "0.12.9"
>   cached_network_image: ^1.0.0   google_places_picker: ^2.0.2+1

Comment: Did you tried `flutter clean`?

Comment: @divyanshubhargava yes I did thank you

Comment: Is it working or you still facing this problem?

Comment: @divyanshubhargava it is not working, I have tried flutter clean prior to asking the question.

Comment: If you're still facing the issue (two and a half months later, I doubt it, but anyway), can you show your build.gradle? It's possible you didn't add the google-services.json  into the android/app directory and the google-services dependency in the android/build.gradle file.

Comment: @Benjamin thanks, yes the google-services.json file was in the app directory and as a dependancy in build.gradle file. We have since find a workaround by rolling back to a previous version and hoping with the next update it should be good.

Answer (score -1):

Please include `firebase_core: ^0.4.0+1` in pubspec.yaml file.

Then run Get Packages. Then use your code.
It should run fine. Else Run `flutter clean` after add the dependency.
For further installation Guide please go through the official Documentation.
[FireBaseCore](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core)